# How much diesel fuel would you need to generate as much power as a kilogram of average nuclear fuel?

Tags: energy

I'd like to be able to visualize the volumes associated with conventional fuels vs. nuclear fuels. Links to source material would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight off the interwebs:

The energy density of diesel is 38.6 megajoules per liter.
The energy density of U-235 is 80,620,000 megajoules per liter.

The ratio of U-235 to diesel is then 80,620,000/38.6 meaning that one liter of U-235 packs as much punch as ~2,088,000 liters of diesel.

One cubic meter contains 1000 liters, meaning that the diesel equivalent displaces ~2088 cubic meters.

Comment: Awesome! Where did you find that?

Comment: 2088 cubic meters is 16 1/2 railroad tankers, which is a non SI unit.